# Smooth connection of curves

Tags: taylor-expansion

The classic example 
$f(x) = 0$ for $x\leq 0$, $f(x) = \exp(-1/x^2)$ for $x>0$
shows that we can "glue" a straight line and a curve,
retaining infinite smoothness at the connection point.

So, what makes this function structurally different
from, say, $\sin(x)$, which, by Taylor series,
is uniquely determined by its value and all derivatives at $0$.

Comment: You are pointing out the difference between two functions classes $C^{\infty}$ and $C^{\omega}$ (*real* analytic ; most papers you will find are about *complex* analytic functions). See (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1412951).

Comment: The first function has an _essential singularity_ at 0, even though that might not be immediately obvious from looking at real arguments alone.

Comment: Isn't it not enough structural difference that one has a converging Taylor series (converging to itself), and the other has not? What else you need an explanation for?